# CAML query not working on another list

Tags: javascript, caml-query, display-form

So Ive been sitting for half a day already trying to solve that. I have been able to successfully run the following query to find a value of another column on a small test-list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var raz = "raz";
var queryLookup = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>raz</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
var itemfield="";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Testowa",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='kolumna'/></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: queryLookup,
    completefunc: function(xData,Status) { 
        itemfield = $(xData.responseText).find("z\\:row").attr("ows_kolumna");;
alert(xData.responseText);
      } 
   });

  alert(itemfield); 

});
```

but as soon as I try applying it to a bigger list (less than 5k elements though) it just does not want to work and gives me no elements found and the following message in console: 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'B' of undefined or null reference
shellcoreprimeg2m_6bed6c50.js (22,23129)

[image: Messege I get]

Does anyone have any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: From the xml it shows that it returns 0 items , Please make sure that the caml query returns the required list item , test this query using CAML Builder and check the results .

Comment: I just did and it finds a result when i search using the title column that contains unique ID which is just a string of letters and numbers. But when i try to search using the name column (and that is what i want to do) it does not find any. An example of the name Im using is: "Płyta Plexiglas gs standard bezbarwny 2mm 2030x3050". Could this be too complicated a string for it to search for?

Comment: I just checked with a simple name "aaa" and it does find a result. Problem is I can't really change the names of the products (all 15000 of them especially...) so any ideas how could i make it work with the long names?

Comment: try to build a query with filter option contains instead of equals to ...

Comment: I don't think you can use "contains" in CAML when you have more than 5000 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution I think - just playing around with the CAML builder. It appears that if you change `<FieldRef Name='Title'/>` to `<FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>` it suddenly starts working.

Answering some comments: It does not matter if I use contains or Eq, it did not work for both, but it works for both now. The list has less than 5000 items.

I hope this helps if someone runs into a similar problem.